Properly Configuring Host Port Fowarding to QEMU/KVM Guest
Can someone please show me what i am still doing wrong with the port fowarding on my KVM host?
If i try to go to the port 22596 from localhost it still doesn't forward to 8096 as specified. The connection is refused
What else needs to be done so that Jellyfin is accessible to other users outside of the kvm network / host's network?
I set the forwarding in firewalld on the host
`     ╰─λ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public
public (default, active)
  target: default
  ingress-priority: 0
  egress-priority: 0
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: wlp9s0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client kdeconnect
  ports: 22596/tcp 1714-1716/tcp 1714-1716/udp 22596/udp 22522/tcp 22580/tcp 22543/tcp
  protocols: tcp udp
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
        port=22596:proto=tcp:toport=8096:toaddr=10.5.20.168
        port=22596:proto=udp:toport=8096:toaddr=10.5.20.168
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
`

I set the hostfwd option in qemu
`    <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-netdev'/>
    <qemu:arg value='user,id=vtnet21,net=0.0.0.0/24,hostfwd=tcp::22596-:8096'/>
    <qemu:arg value='-device'/>
    <qemu:arg value='virtio,netdev=vtnet21'/>
 </qemu:commandline>`

When i go to the guest in question (called Media_Server) i can reach it from the host's Jellyfin webadmin at 10.4.20.66:8096
Its behind a virtual OPNsense firewall so i'm also able to go to the firewall's WAN 10.5.20.253:8096 and get to the server
But i can't use the web browser to go to localhost:22596 or 172.16.4.55:22596 (host physical nic ip address) the connection is refused.
